# keyboard jumbled after using keybd_event

Tags: c#, keyboard

Hi I have a c# application that uses keybd_event to virtually simulate key presses. When I run the application all of the key presses work fine. However, after I close my application some of my keys on the keyboard get jumbled in that when I press a certain key the default command does not happen.

Thanks.

Comment: Care to show some code or something before your question gets closed as not a real such?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you forgot to release a modifier key that you “pressed” programmatically. Make sure to call `keybd_event` with the `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` option for every key you press.

Here is an example of pressing `Ctrl`+`Q`:

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_Q, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_Q, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

If you forget the last line, then all your subsequent key presses – even if manually performed by the user – would be interpreted as if the `Ctrl` key were still pressed.

Comment: Thanks I had the Windows key down which messed up my key board inputs.